# Is it safe to change the Recovery Model of SSRS database ReportServer to SIMPLE?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I'm changing the recovery model of ReportServer database from FULL to SIMPLE.

Is there any reason why i *would not* want to do this? Besides the obvious answer of losing point-in-time recovery? (i am not doing transaction log backups on this database anyways.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're not taking transaction log backups, you don't want to use the FULL recovery model. It's that simple.

[image: SQL Server Database Properties - ReportServer Database]

- Set the **Recovery model** to **Simple** and click **OK** to change.
- It is recommended to perform a FULL backup of the database after changing the **Recovery model**.

Comment: you don't only need it, you actually should not use FULL mode if you are not backing your logs. Otherwise the .ldf file will eventually fill your hdd